# Release only on certain Ubuntu platform?

Tags: ros, bloom-release, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example on `Indigo`, can I exclude certain Ubuntu distro, say Saucy, upon making a release? Well it looks like it's not possible at this momement, but is it planned to become possible in the future? I don't mean it's necessary for any of my purpose for now but I'm just curious and sounds like it's convenient.

While releasing a package into Indigo, I found a DEB of one of the dependencies, python-termcolor ([ticketed](https://github.com/start-jsk/rtmros_hironx/pull/437)), is not available only on Saucy (ie. [available on Trusty onward](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/99695ed25cd53ad0c113ed2f6efe0fb24fc98140/rosdep/python.yaml#L1885-L1923)).

Apparently `rosdep` (run during `bloom` process) couldn't resolve the dependency and gave an error, but then bloom offered an option to skip it (log1). Combined with [a recent announcement](http://lists.ros.org/lurker/message/20160203.215925.082bb8bd.en.html), I thought I could somehow move forward making a release into Indio except on Saucy platform. Turned out I was wrong (I then got a bunch of error emails from buildfarm (log2) stating that a release branch for Saucy wasn't found).

log1

```
==> git-bloom-generate -y rosdebian --prefix release/indigo indigo -i 0
Generating source debs for the packages: ['hironx_calibration', 'hironx_moveit_config', 'hironx_ros_bridge', 'rtmros_hironx']
Debian Incremental Version: 0
Debian Distributions: ['saucy', 'trusty']
Releasing for rosdistro: indigo

Pre-verifying Debian dependency keys...
Running 'rosdep update'...
Key 'python-termcolor' resolved to '['termcolor']' with installer 'pip', which does not match the default installer 'apt'.
Failed to resolve python-termcolor on ubuntu:saucy with: Error running generator: The Debian generator does not support dependencies which are installed with the 'pip' installer.
python-termcolor is depended on by these packages: ['hironx_ros_bridge']
<== Failed
Some of the dependencies for packages in this repository could not be resolved by rosdep.
You can try to address the issues which appear above and try again if you wish.
Would you like to try again? [Y/n]? n
User aborted after rosdep keys were not resolved.
<== The following generator action reported that it is missing one or more
    rosdep keys, but that the key exists in other platforms:
'['/usr/bin/git-bloom-generate', '-y', 'rosdebian', '--prefix', 'release/indigo', 'indigo', '-i', '0']'

If you are absolutely sure that this key is unavailable for the platform in
question, the generator can be skipped and you can proceed with the release.
Skip generator action and continue with release [y/N]? y

Action skipped, continuing with release.

==> git-bloom-generate -y rosrpm --prefix release/indigo indigo -i 0
Generating source RPMs for the packages: ['hironx_calibration', 'hironx_moveit_config', 'hironx_ros_bridge', 'rtmros_hironx']
RPM Incremental Version: 0
RPM Distributions: ['21', 'heisenbug']
Releasing for rosdistro: indigo

Pre-verifying RPM dependency keys...
Running 'rosdep update'...
Key 'python-termcolor' resolved to '['termcolor']' with installer 'pip', which does not match the default installer 'yum'.
Failed to resolve python-termcolor on fedora:21 with: Error running generator: The RPM generator does not support dependencies which are installed with the 'pip' installer.
python-termcolor is depended on by these packages: ['hironx_ros_bridge']
<== Failed
Key 'python-termcolor' resolved to '['termcolor']' with installer 'pip', which does not match the default installer 'yum'.
Failed to resolve python-termcolor on fedora:heisenbug with: Error running generator: The RPM generator does not support dependencies which are installed with the 'pip' installer.
python-termcolor is depended on by these packages: ['hironx_ros_bridge']
<== Failed
Some of the dependencies for packages in this repository could not be resolved by rosdep.
You can try to address the issues which appear above and try again if you wish.
Would you like to try again? [Y/n]? 
Running 'rosdep update'...
Key 'python-termcolor' resolved to '['termcolor']' with installer 'pip', which does not match the default installer 'yum'.
Failed to resolve python-termcolor on fedora:21 with: Error running generator: The RPM generator does not support dependencies which are installed with the 'pip' installer.
python-termcolor is depended on by these packages: ['hironx_ros_bridge']
<== Failed
Key 'python-termcolor' resolved to '['termcolor']' with installer 'pip', which does not match the default installer 'yum'.
Failed to resolve python-termcolor on fedora:heisenbug with: Error running generator: The RPM generator does not support dependencies which are installed with the 'pip' installer.
python-termcolor is depended on by these packages: ['hironx_ros_bridge']
<== Failed
Some of the dependencies for packages in this repository could not be resolved by rosdep.
You can try to address the issues which appear above and try again if you wish.
Would you like to try again? [Y/n]? n
User aborted after rosdep keys were not resolved.
<== The following generator action reported that it is missing one or more
    rosdep keys, but that the key exists in other platforms:
'['/usr/bin/git-bloom-generate', '-y', 'rosrpm', '--prefix', 'release/indigo', 'indigo', '-i', '0']'

If you are absolutely sure that this key is unavailable for the platform in
question, the generator can be skipped and you can proceed with the release.
Skip generator action and continue with release [y/N]? y

Action skipped, continuing with release.
```

log2

```
# BEGIN SUBSECTION: get sources
Invoking 'git clone --branch debian/ros-indigo-rtmros-hironx_1.1.9-0_saucy --depth 1 --no-single-branch https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_hironx-release.git /tmp/sourcedeb/source'
Cloning into '/tmp/sourcedeb/source'...
fatal: Remote branch debian/ros-indigo-rtmros-hironx_1.1.9-0_saucy not found in upstream origin
Unexpected end of command stream
# END SUBSECTION
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ros_buildfarm/scripts/release/get_sources.py", line 34, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ros_buildfarm/scripts/release/get_sources.py", line 30, in main
    args.os_name, args.os_code_name, args.source_dir)
  File "/tmp/ros_buildfarm/ros_buildfarm/sourcedeb_job.py", line 35, in get_sources
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 547, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'clone', '--branch', 'debian/ros-indigo-rtmros-hironx_1.1.9-0_saucy', '--depth', '1', '--no-single-branch', 'https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_hironx-release.git', '/tmp/sourcedeb/source']' returned non-zero exit status 128
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
[description-setter] Could not determine description.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226348/release-only-on-certain-ubuntu-platform?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not planned to support custom set of distributions. Simply because one ROS distribution aims to provide a certain set and not diverge across various Ubuntu distributions.

That being set your specific problem might be resolved by the fact that EOL Ubuntu distributions will be not be built for in the near future. See http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2016-February/069828.html for more information on that.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-02-11**:
Ok, I think I just misinterpret Tully's announcement. Now I understand that once Saucy's build reaches EOLed for Indigo, 1) all Indigo build jobs for Saucy will be stopped, 2) and maintainers will not have an option for excluding certain platforms (same as we have not had).